# Namespace and class have the same name

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I have inherited a large c# project. One of the classes has a namespace and class which share the same name. As a result when making an instance of the class i have to do this:

```
using xxx.existingName
IinterfaceName dog = new existingName.existingName();
```

Since the existing class has an interface i am able to avoid having `existingName.existingName` on the left of the `=`. Using `var dog` would also do this. However i also want to avoid `existingName.existingName` being used on the right hand side because it is less readable.

Is there any way to do this without renaming the existing code?

Comment: `using dog = existingName::existingName;`?

Answer (score 3):

You could rename the class or the namespace via the `using` directive:

```
using ClassAlias = Test.Test;
using NamespaceAlias = Test;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ClassAlias a = new ClassAlias();
        NamespaceAlias.Test t = new NamespaceAlias.Test();
    }
}

namespace Test{
    public class Test{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could  use an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#namespace-aliases) to make this more readable(well, not with these names):

```
using AliasForName = existingName;
```

...

```
IinterfaceName dog = new AliasForName.existingName();
```

If the original author would have looked at [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces), he would have used a different name in the first place:

> **X DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that
>   namespace** . For example, do not use `Debug` as a namespace name and then
>   also provide a class named `Debug` in the same namespace. Several
>   compilers require such types to be fully qualified.

By the way, you should really apply [capitaliation conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

Comment: If they we're following those conventions, they wouldn't be in this situation in the first place since the namespace naming conventions say not to use the same name for a namespace and a type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: added